# Is there a way of forcing a hardlink on fat32?

Tags: linux, filesystems, fat32

Both cp -l and ln refuse to create hard links on Fat32 FS, even when used with -F option by root. This is a sensible behaviour, since having fat no reference count it is really likely to mess up things.
Yet is there a way to force different directory entries to point to the same start block, under my only responsability (i.e. FS being used as read-only)?
I did it e.g. for iso9660, that is not designed to have links either.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Normally, NO there are no utilities to do this.  However, ***at your own peril be it***, you can sector edit the hard drive and point one directory cluster to the other one.

**Running chkdsk or any repair tool will see this as an error and attempt to correct it.**  Thus undoing what you did, and have the potential for messing up your file system.